# sometimes Owl Carousel Slider not working

Tags: magento2, owl-carousel

Now the magento site version is 2.4.3. It's using the owl carousel for banner image and product images.
And the owl carousel works well. But sometimes it isn't working.
I think it's because the owl carousel js loads before the jquery js loaded.
It returns this error. **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fn')
at owl.carousel.js:1713:4
at owl.carousel.js:1750:3**

I imported the owl carousel js with require js.

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'owlcarousel': 'Magento_Theme/js/owl.carousel'
    },
    shim: {
        'owlcarousel': ['jquery']
    }
};

require(['jquery'], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $.noConflict();
});
```

Is there anyone can check this? And let me know the solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Can you follow below setps.

Step 1:Please open **`owl.carousel.js`** file and add below code at the top of actual jquery(**`owl.carousel.js`**) script

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function () {
```

and now add the end bracket at the end of the jquery(**`owl.carousel.js`**) file.

its done for **`owl.carousel.js`**.

After changes run below commands.

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

If any query let me know.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Ok, let me check.
But is it possible to add the define jquery to the additional js file?

Comment: yes it is possible.

Comment: It doesn't show any error in the console. But the slider isn't working.